# Promote a field error to a form error

Tags: redux-form

redux-form version: v6.2.0

I have a credit card info form. (number, expiry, cvc). I don't have enough space for an error on each field, so I want just 1 form-level error field instead of many field-level input field errors.

This would be easy enough to do with form-level validation (adding an `_error: firstFieldLevelError`) but I don't want to show it unless that field has been touched (and of course `touched` is only available to the field).

So, I resorted to grabbing it manually out of the state:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  const formState = state.form[props.form];
  if (formState) {
    const {syncErrors} = formState;
    if (syncErrors) {
      const firstErrorField = Object.keys(syncErrors)[0];
      const {touched} = formState.fields[firstErrorField] || {};
      if (touched) {
        return {
          syncFormError: syncErrors[firstErrorField]
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return {};
};
```

Pretty darn verbose for what I imagine to be something pretty common. Is there a better way?

Comment: yep, willing to upgrade to a newer version, but that's what i'm on right now. `

Comment: _"...verbose for what I imagine to be something pretty common"_ - well, not actually. I'm a Redux Form maintainer for some time now, and this is the first time I see this idea :)

Comment: @gustavohenke heh, touché, although i did use this method back in v4 and below (it was trivial to implement back then iirc). would you be opposed to passing `props.errors` with a touched prop down in addition to `props.error`? Then the dev could pick the first one or combine them all or do whatever they like.

Comment: Go ahead and make your proposal as a GitHub issue. The discussion is likely to increase, so we could evolve it over there.